# how get checked all row from all pages in Antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

In table component I have pagination with few pages and I need to add event on it to count all properties from all pages. Right now when I clicking on it , it checks rows only on current page. Or may be there is any way to find out that top checkbox was clicked?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The other pages aren't rendered so they aren't mounted.
Therefore they don't exist in the real DOM or React's virtual DOM.

The solution would be to still render the other pages.
But to return nulls in all of the components so it is still invisible.

That would however defeat the purpose of pagination.
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onSelectAll` of [`rowSelection`](https://ant.design/components/table/#rowSelection)

```
const App = () => {
  const rowSelection = {
    onSelectAll: () => console.log('all Selected')
  };
  return (
    <Table rowSelection={rowSelection} columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Q-59028497-onSelectAll]

Comment: I tried select all but it is also giving rows in current page https://codesandbox.io/s/selection-and-operation-antd-4-17-0-alpha-9-forked-ix2mp?file=/index.js